# Ext js 5.0.1 column custom sorting

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel

I am new to extjs framework and looking for a way to add a custom sorting function to a column in a panel. I went through some of the post, and it seems that this functionality has been changed a few times over time.

In 5.0.1 documentation I found [sortType](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-sortType) configuration that can be used to convert the data to a comparable value.

But in my case, converting all the data to a value and then sorting could be a time consuming process and I was looking to use a function like the one used in `doSort` configuration earlier [similar to this example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2u7&view/editor); by basically configuring a function like this:

```
function customSorter(state){
    var ds = this.up('grid').getStore();
    var field = this.getSortParam();
    ds.sort({
        property: field,
        direction: state,
        sorterFn: function(v1,v2){
             //some custom logic
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 1:** *I am looking to use this function for only one column, the other columns are standard data types and sorting works fine by default for those.*

Any ideas how to do this in 5.0.1?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: As you mentioned this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2u7&view/editor). So you can use same

Comment: @NarendraJadhav this fiddlle uses a different version of ext, when I try the same with the required version, it fails. Try once by changing the version to 5.0.1 in the top right and try to run the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of `Ext.util.Sorter` to the `sort` method of your store. The  `Ext.util.Sorter` class has an `sorterFn` config.

references:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.util.Sorter.html 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.data.Store.html#method-sort

If you want to have a custom sort for a specific colum you can use the `sortType` config on the field corresponding to the column, see https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-sortType

Comment: I looked into these documentations, but what I was looking for is a comparator function for one of the columns. The other columns are working fine, I don't want the new sorter function to be used for all the fields. Sorry if the question was not clear,  will edit this

Comment: you can use https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-sortType for this, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that link is already there in the question, I found that earlier. But the problem with that is to convert all the data of the field to a numeric value is a large computation and slow process. That is why i was looking for a way to use a function that takes 2 arguments and returns -1.0,1 depending on the comparison, which should be a faster activity. Any idea with that?

Comment: ah sorry I did not see that the link was already in your question. I don't know how to do this :(